# php code to print 1 between fromdate and todate

Tags: php, mysql

Table name receipt
coupondate - varchar

```
coupondate    customer      
 02-04-2015     A    
 05-04-2015     B
```

if user select fromdate = 01-04-2015 , todate = 30-04-2015 in form and click submit..then i display all days between fromdate and todate like below...

```
Customer  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29   30
  A           p  p  p  p p  p  p  p   p  p  p   p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p   p p  p  p  p  p   p   
  B                   p  p  p  p  p   p  p  p   p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p  p p  p   p   p
```

now i need to match this date with coupondate column...

**FOR EX -** In above table customer A present from 02-04-2015 ..so i need to display p below customer A from 02-04 upto 30..

same for Customer B...

plz help me to achieve my expected output...

**below code i used to display days in header rows..**

```
<?php
$startdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
$enddate = $_POST['todate'];
$start = date('d', strtotime($startdate));
$end=date('d', strtotime($enddate));
?>
```

**below code prints days from 01 to 30 in header rows..**

```
<?php for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) {?>
    <th width="58%"><?php echo $x; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
```

below is my sql query...

```
SELECT RE.*,min(RE.coupondate) As mindate,max(RE.coupondate) As Maxdate FROM receipt_entry RE LEFT JOIN city_master CM ON RE.city_name = CM.id WHERE CM.cityname = :cityname AND str_to_date(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate GROUP BY RE.receipt_no
```

below code is used to echo p...below all days...

```
   <?php  if (is_array($data)) { foreach($data as $row) {   ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>                    
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['customer_name']); ?></td> 

            <?php for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) {?>                                   
            <?php if($row['mindate'] == $x) { ?>        

            <td>P</td>                      
            <?php } else { ?>           
            <?php } } ?>  
        </tr>
        <?php } }?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Any reason you're not using MySQL's built-in date/time features and storing yours as varchar? Using those would make querying a lot easier.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion... but i need to achieve my output...on first priority.......i tried this  later...

Comment: Your first priority should be to correctly store your data. It affects everything you do in your system and the more you code against this incorrect schema the more you are digging yourself into a hole

Comment: sir...i change this in database from varchar to date